# textView height equal to content size without viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating a viewController which contain 2 textViews a title and a fullText. At the moment i've created 2 textViews in the interface builder which is placed below each other and then created following code to change the height to equal to the content. However the issue is that it seem to be delayed, which gives a bad user experience. By delay i mean that it takes 0.5 or 1 sec before it resize? here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    setHeightToContent(self.titleText!)
    setHeightToContent(self.fullText!)

    scrollView?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.fullText!.frame.origin.y + self.fullText!.frame.height)
    println(self.fullText!.frame.origin.y + self.fullText!.frame.height)



}


func setHeightToContent(theTextView: UITextView) {

    let contentSize = theTextView.sizeThatFits(theTextView.bounds.size)
    var frame = theTextView.frame
    frame.size.height = contentSize.height
    theTextView.frame = frame

    var aspectRatioTextViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: theTextView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: theTextView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: theTextView.bounds.height/theTextView.bounds.width, constant: 1)
    theTextView.addConstraint(aspectRatioTextViewConstraint)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each of the text views self-sizing in accordance with its own content, and use constraints so that the scroll view's `contentSize` is configured automatically based on its content.

Comment: how do i make them self-sizing i thought that was what i was doing in setHeightToContent

Comment: You are, but you're calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You want to do it at nib load time and then, if the content can change, in response to that. (Indeed, that may be in part the cause of the delay, since you are doing layout in response to layout having been done.)

Comment: Also, I'm not saying you're making this mistake, but just to be sure: don't use a text view if a label will do. A label is very, very good at sizing itself to the height of its content. So if the user does not need to type in this thing, use a label, not a text view.

Comment: Okay i think i understand, would this require me to create the UILabels programmatically in order to resize at nib load

Comment: With proper constraints and `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, a label's height _is_ self-sizing. And the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is automatic by default in iOS 8. So they do not have to be "created programmatically". It just works.